# Confusing behavior of java.beans.PropertyDescriptor(String, Class)

Tags: java, javabeans

I'm trying to create a PropertyDescriptor for a bean class I have.  I am calling

```
new PropertyDescriptor(myProperty, myClass)
```

and am seeing an exception that the method "isMyProperty" does not exist.
Peeking into the code a bit --

```
/**
 * Constructs a PropertyDescriptor for a property that follows
 * the standard Java convention by having getFoo and setFoo
 * accessor methods.  Thus if the argument name is "fred", it will
 * assume that the writer method is "setFred" and the reader method
 * is "getFred" (or "isFred" for a boolean property).  Note that the
 * property name should start with a lower case character, which will
 * be capitalized in the method names.
 *
 * @param propertyName The programmatic name of the property.
 * @param beanClass The Class object for the target bean.  For
 *      example sun.beans.OurButton.class.
 * @exception IntrospectionException if an exception occurs during
 *              introspection.
 */
public PropertyDescriptor(String propertyName, Class<?> beanClass)
    throws IntrospectionException {
this(propertyName, beanClass, 
     "is" + capitalize(propertyName), 
     "set" + capitalize(propertyName));
}
```

The documentation says that it will look for "getFred" but it always uses `"is" + capitalize(property)`!  This is in java version "1.6.0_31"

Thoughts?

Comment: Is `myProperty` a boolean property?

Comment: This really looks like a bug. My explanation is that `PropertyDescriptor`s are not normally instantiated directly, but by going through the `Introspector` and `BeanInfo`. Still, this is public API.

Comment: @srjavin: Where does it even check whether it's a boolean or not?  No, in this case it's not -- that's why I am so confused that I get "no such method isMyProperty"

Comment: HI Steven.  Did my answer address your question?  I think in your specific case, you are getting this error because the property does not exist.

Comment: @StevenSchlansker: Method getReadMethod() is no more synchronized in the newer version of java. I have some legacy code which is breaking because of this. Can you please check my question posted today related to this and suggest some workaround you might have.. thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** I think I know what your problem is.  If the property doesn't exist in your class, then you will get the "isProperty" method error. See my example:

```
    {
        PropertyDescriptor desc = new PropertyDescriptor("uuid", Company.class);
        Method m = desc.getReadMethod();
        System.out.println(m.getName()); /* prints getUuid */
    }
    {
        PropertyDescriptor desc = new PropertyDescriptor("uuid11", Company.class);
        Method m = desc.getReadMethod();
        System.out.println(m.getName()); /* throws Method not found: isUuid11 */
    }
```

---

**Original:**

It looks like it just defaults to isProperty as the read method, and if it doesn't exists, it uses getProperty.  Take a look at the `getReadMethod` method, the bit where it goes:

```
if (readMethod == null) {
    readMethodName = "get" + getBaseName();
```

So it's trying the isProperty method first, and if it doesn't have that method, looks for getProperty.

Here's the full method:

```
public synchronized Method getReadMethod() {
Method readMethod = getReadMethod0();
if (readMethod == null) {
    Class cls = getClass0();
    if (cls == null || (readMethodName == null && readMethodRef == null)) {
        // The read method was explicitly set to null.
        return null;
    }
    if (readMethodName == null) {
        Class type = getPropertyType0();
        if (type == boolean.class || type == null) {
            readMethodName = "is" + getBaseName();
        } else {
            readMethodName = "get" + getBaseName();
        }
    }

    // Since there can be multiple write methods but only one getter
    // method, find the getter method first so that you know what the
    // property type is.  For booleans, there can be "is" and "get"
    // methods.  If an "is" method exists, this is the official
    // reader method so look for this one first.
    readMethod = Introspector.findMethod(cls, readMethodName, 0);
    if (readMethod == null) {
        readMethodName = "get" + getBaseName();
        readMethod = Introspector.findMethod(cls, readMethodName, 0);
    }
    try {
        setReadMethod(readMethod);
    } catch (IntrospectionException ex) {
    // fall
    }
}
return readMethod;
}
```

Comment: But readMethodName is the very same property that is set in the constructor -- so making it isFoo suppresses the bit of code that you're quoting!  In fact, the constructor checks that the readMethodName is not null (unless you specify the Method object directly, which totally defeats the purpose in my case)

Comment: I've reformatted the code to make it a bit easier to read.  what has been set in the constructor is readMethodName.  If that is set, it will call Introspector.findMethod(readMethodName), if null is returned, it looks for the "get" method.

Comment: Wow, what awful code to find in the JDK... there are about 50 clearer ways to write this :P

Answer (score 2):

If your property is primitive boolean then PropertyDescriptor looking for "isProperty" method.
If your property is boxed Boolean then PropertyDescriptor looking for "getProperty" method.

Comment: This was exactly our problem. Very not-obvious and very annoying, took a loooong time to find!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved like this.

```
static Object get(final String name, final Object obj)
    throws ReflectiveOperationException {

    final Class<?> klass = obj.getClass();

    try {
        final BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(klass);
        for (final PropertyDescriptor descriptor
             : info.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
            if (name.equals(descriptor.getName())) {
                final Method reader = descriptor.getReadMethod();
                if (reader != null) {
                    if (!reader.isAccessible()) {
                        reader.setAccessible(true);
                    }
                    return reader.invoke(obj);
                }
                break; // anyway
            }
        }
    } catch (final IntrospectionException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }

    final Field field = findField(obj.getClass(), name);
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, "trying to get value directly from {0}",
               new Object[]{field});
    if (!field.isAccessible()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
    }
    return field.get(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a field named "ip_value". 
My initial getter and setter methods were `getIPValue()` and `setIPValue()` respectively.
After renaming them to `getIp_value()` and `setIp_value()` respectively the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Having got the same "no such method isMyProperty" exception and reading all of the above, I re-checked the obvious... my bad.

Double check you actually have the correct getX and a setX.
Specifically check the function signatures.

I didn't. Don't you hate it when that happens ;)
PICNIC